# TeamCity NuGet Pack - Include Release Notes in Command Line

Tags: teamcity, nuget, nuget-package

When using the TeamCity Pack NuGet Build step, there is a little box at the bottom of the page allow ing you to specify additional command line arguments.

I wonder, is there a way to push the VCS logs to the NuGet release notes via the command line?

Or, is there another way to get TeamCity to update NuGet Package release notes to include the VCS commit messages?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not by using the commandline.

I use [GitReleaseNotes](https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/GitReleaseNotes) to generate my release notes from git commits. You could run that before you pack the NuGet Package and include it as readme file for the package or have another build step inbetween that updates  in NuSpec from the generated file.